# JSON Extractor : Extract from Sampler Result and from response and use in another HTTP request

Tags: json, path, jmeter, extractor

I am new to JMeter and trying to extract the ApplicationCookie from Sampler Result, which looks like below

.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=j6rRWJLR44frKxJn3skUv-W1cHe0zJWyBccvG2qZyYuPcvUgnd4riCf69aqxy_T4JHRl3uepcEPtUAZA3Fw7VKR32ar4AX3rjx2Dobv6Vh-vPXWKeA30bGNoWCbQtvUBPoZS2MWiqOcTmEK-y-wi57u_wdEhp3pCnFlexJFygzkZAz63HK-HaqNmHJEO6cbAsBWWP0ZyKXZJuTeNtldNVwPggpZwpxH4h9DtwaaygV1GAYLApYPdCQRNrBXDzZFsmNlid33LqY96OX7H_K7MrOG4lEn8A_CiHlFA5PjkWEXjzVng; domain=blah-blah-blah; path=/; HttpOnly

**and** 
from response data, I would like to extract a Token value, which is as follows

{
 "Token": "5c282752-202e-4f21-a93f-681aba15c7d4",
 "Time": 1200
}

**Not** sure if I am extracting it in the right way!

[image]

and trying to use the extracted variables as below in next HTTP request (that closes the session)

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: JSONPath should be I think `$.Token` and when you refer to MyToken in HTTP Request, you should put it in brackets with dollar sign, e.g. `${MyToken}`

Comment: Thanks, Kiril for the help.